# Search box missing in Ubuntu Software 20.04

Tags: software-center, 20.04

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04. Everything seems to be working fine, except that I can't find a search box when I start Ubuntu Software... Where is it hidden?

When I click on the listed categories, after a few secs, it loads and displays the list for the corresponding category, but still no search box!

Comment: Click the thing at the top left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Gunnar Hjalmarsson mentioned, there is a tiny magnifying glass icon in the top left corner when the "explore" tab is selected.